# Not always + inversion?

Tags: word-order, negation, subject-verb-inversion

My neighbour's little son (they are from UK) asked me for something, saying that he wants it and hence he will get.
I realized I do not know how to say that correctly (for the first one I used inversion)

> Not always gets the person what he wants.

or

> It is not that everytime you wants something you will get it.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the first sentence uses a form frequently used in proverbs. Does it originate from old English?

Answer (score 3):

I would say

> We don't always get what we want.

or, if I were feeling formal, I might say

> One doesn't always get what one wants.

I believe that the latter may be ungrammatical in American English, but it's OK in other dialects.

Comment: But if you try, sometimes...

Comment: Yes, the Rolling Stones answered this question in 1969. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIX0ZDqDljA

Comment: Ungrammatical? Huh??

Comment: I thought the right form in American English was "one doesn't always get what _he_ wants".  But I wasn't sure, which is why I said "may be".

Comment: No, "one doesn't always get what one wants" is perfectly fine in American English. While "he" would have been fine thirty years ago, many people wouldn't use "he" nowadays because it's not gender neutral, and "one doesn't always get what they want" sounds wrong to me (despite the fact that I use the singular "they" often).

Comment: @David: I learned things too; I found an [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+finds+oneself%2Cone+finds+himself%2Cone+finds+herself%2Cone+finds+themself&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) which illustrates the replacement of "one ... him" with "one ... one" in the U.S. It started before people worried about gender neutrality, but gender neutrality is finishing the job. The corresponding British Ngram shows "one ... him" was never used much in the U.K.

Answer (score 0):

No inversion is required. *We don't always get what we want* or *You don't always get what you want* is all you need.